# Excel VBA change cell color if it's today's date

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am not very good at VBA and would not even call myself a "programmer." I'm trying to use Excel VBA to change the color of a cell yellow with black bold text if its value is today's date. The data comes in like this "06/20/22 8:00". So I'm trying to apply the int() function to remove the information that's not a date such as the time. When I run the code, I get an error "type mismatch" but even if that error is resolved, I'm not sure this code would even work. The code works to change the cell color based on the other criteria. The only part that does not work is at the end my attempt to get the code to change the cell value based on today's date. Thank you for all your help.

```
Sub Color_Cell_Condition()

Dim MyCell As Range
Dim StatValue As String
Dim DateValue As Date
Dim SubjectRange As Range
Dim EventTypeRange As Range
Dim EventDateRange As Range

Set SubjectRange = Range("DSubject")
Set EventTypeRange = Range("DEventType")
Set EventDateRange = Range("DDateRange")

For Each MyCell In SubjectRange

StatValue = MyCell.Value
Select Case StatValue

    Case "Court"
    MyCell.Interior.Color = RGB(192, 0, 0)
    
    Case "Deadline"
    MyCell.Interior.Color = RGB(32, 55, 100)
    
    Case "Appointment"
    MyCell.Interior.Color = RGB(55, 86, 35)

End Select

Next MyCell

For Each MyCell In EventTypeRange

StatValue = MyCell.Value
Select Case StatValue

    Case "Joint Scheduling Report"
    MyCell.Interior.Color = RGB(169, 208, 142)
    MyCell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    
    Case "Joint Pretrial Stipulation"
    MyCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 102, 0)
    MyCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    MyCell.Font.Bold = True
    
    Case "Statement of Claim"
    MyCell.Interior.Color = RGB(165, 165, 165)
    MyCell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    
    Case "Response to Motion"
    MyCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    MyCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    MyCell.Font.Bold = True

End Select

Next MyCell

For Each MyCell In EventDateRange

DateValue = Int(MyCell.Value)
Select Case DateValue

    Case Date
    MyCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    MyCell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    MyCell.Font.Bold = True

End Select

Next MyCell


End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure the date is actually a date and not a string that looks like one? Side question: Is there a reason you are not using Conditional formatting for this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: One problem I see is that you need something to call this function. An event (worksheet load, cell change) or a timer would be required, otherwise, the code will never run. Wrt is the value a date or not, you can pass it into a function called `IsDate()`, which returns true/1 if the format is considered to be a date. You can use the immediate window to test this.

Comment: Also "So I'm trying to apply the `int()` function to remove the information that's not a date such as the time". By doing this, you're converting the date to an integer, so it won't be a date anymore. Better to use the `left`, `mid` or `instr` functions to trim the text after the date.

Comment: cybernetic.noma - I'm not using conditional formatting because this data comes from the cloud through a Devart addon and everytime the data refreshes, Devart recreates the table and reloads the data, which screws up the conditional formatting date range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having added my comments to the question, I realise you're overcomplicating this. If you just want to colour a cell based on whether it's today, just use this

```
Dim myCell As Range


For Each myCell In .Range("A1:Z99")
    If isdate(myCell) then
        If format(myCell.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") = format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy") Then
            myCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            myCell.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    End if
Next
End With
```

You should put this on a timer, or put it inside an event.

Comment: Thank you! This works with some modifications!

Comment: This is the code that worked based on what you wrote: For Each MyCell In EventDateRange
    If IsDate(MyCell) Then
        If Format(MyCell.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy") Then
            MyCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            MyCell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            MyCell.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    End If
Next

Comment: RGB is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional formatting with the following formula:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(A1,0) = TODAY()
```

Comment: Can't use conditional formatting. This is based on data from a Devart add-on that pulls data from a cloud database. Everytime I refresh the data, Devart recreates and reloads the table. This screws up the conditional formatting ranges.